# How can I iterate over key/value output in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iteration

I am a Powershell newcomer trying to enumerate all the `ExportedCmdlets` in the `pscx` module. I've used `foreach` in powershell before but it doesn't seem to be working with the key/value output from `ExportedCmdlets`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$cmdLets = (Get-Module pscx).ExportedCmdlets
echo $cmdLets
echo '-----------------'
# This is where the script breaks - $cmdLet is the entire set of $cmdLets
foreach ( $cmdLet in ($cmdLets) ) {
  echo $cmdLet
  echo 'next'
}
```

How can I make `$cmdLet` be a single item in `$cmdLets`?

More specifically, **how can I iterate properly over key/value output?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$cmdLets.GetEnumerator()`:

```
foreach ( $cmdLet in $cmdLets.GetEnumerator() ) {
  echo $cmdLet
  echo 'next'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keys` property, ie:

```
$cmdLets = (Get-Module pscx).ExportedCmdlets.Keys
echo $cmdLets
echo '-----------------'
foreach ( $cmdLet in ($cmdLets) ) {
  echo $cmdLet
  echo 'next'
}
```